Is there anway to get a specific keyboard input in python
I'm working on a project for school and it currently has the line input("press enter to continue") which works but it doesn't matter what the input is as as long as the user hits enter to program continues, and i'd like it to only work when that specific key is pressed.
I looked it up and there used to be a keyboard module but for some inexplicable reason it's been removed, so is there any other way of getting an input?

Why would you care what the user might have typed before pressing Enter?  You could do something like while input("press enter to continue"): pass to only accept Enter alone - but the user could STILL type whatever they want, they'd just have to press Enter twice rather than once to continue the program.

You can use readchar library for this purposes. It works for both Linux and Windows and should also work for MacOS but not fully tested (according to the official documentation)
pip install readchar

Here is an example of reaction to the different key-press cases:
from readchar import readkey, key

while True:
  k = readkey()
  if k == "a":
    # do stuff
  if k == key.DOWN:
    # do stuff
  if k == key.ENTER:
    break


A question requesting for a keyboard replacement, Python keyboard module non-functional with python 3.x and macOS? suggests getting https://pypi.org/project/pynput/
Then it has an examples for synchronous waiting, like this loop exits when the Esc key is pressed:
from pynput import keyboard

# The event listener will be running in this block
with keyboard.Events() as events:
    for event in events:
        if event.key == keyboard.Key.esc:
            break
        else:
            print('Received event {}'.format(event))

https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Key is where they list other special keys you may wish to wait for.

If you're using Windows, you can try msvcrt to capture keypresses.
import msvcrt

def wait_for_enter():
    print("Press Enter to continue")
    while True:
        if msvcrt.getch() == b'\r':
            break

wait_for_enter()

If you're using Linux or MacOS, you can try curses.
import curses

def wait_for_enter():
    def main(stdscr):
        stdscr.addstr("Press Enter to continue\n")
        while True:
            key = stdscr.getch()
            if key == curses.KEY_ENTER or key in [10, 13]:
                break

    curses.wrapper(main)

wait_for_enter()

I hope this will help you a little.
